# JQuery Sheet Customization

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I wanted to know if we can customize the [jQuery sheet plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/sheet) according to user requirements, if yes how?

I would also like to know more functions, operations of the sheet plugin. Can we change the functions internally?

Answer (score 6):

Hey Rohan! My name is Robert Plummer, I'm the creator and lead developer of jQuery.sheet.  To answer your question, YES!  With the latest release of jQuery.sheet, customizing calculations has never been easier.  Here is a really quick example:

```
$('#sheetContainer').sheet({
  calculations:{
    SUM_V2: function(value_as_array) {
      var sum = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < value_as_array.length; i++) {
        sum += value_as_array[i];
      }
      return sum;
    }
  }
});
```

Then you can use it inside a cell's value like this:

```
=SUM_V2(A1:A10)
```

Download the latest release here: http://visop-dev.com/Project+jQuery.sheet

Thanks for the interest in my project, if you have any further suggestions, please let me know!